# VisualSVN over distributed machines?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I'm new to SVN. I've downloaded VisualSVN SErver and VisualSVN client with TortoiseSVN.

The problem is: we are group of 4 ppl and are developing a website on ASP.Net. I want the solution file to be in a repository on a machine which can be a server (desktop). The rest are all laptops trying to gather the updated data. We are working from different locations too. I want to know if Apache Subversion can work through the Internet? How can it be configured?

We are all running Windows and Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: You may get a better response if you better word your question.  It's rather difficult to read/parse right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question (see my comment), but if you are wondering the best way to use SVN to manage the development of your ASP.NET website, I don't see why you can't include the solution file directly in the SVN repository.  When your developers want to work on SVN, they sync with the repository and bring down the entire solution (including source, SLN file, properties, etc).  Then, they can work locally on their machine developing the website.

Again, your question is a bit confusing, so I am not sure how else to answer.

**Update**

Thank you for clarifying your question.  If the laptops do not have access to a local server you can do one of two things.

1. If you want to use Subversion, you can setup a server that is internet-facing - AKA, it's accessible from the net.  However, this does require a little bit more work as you will need to have an address for them to point to, etc.  But, in essence, this is no different than accessing on a local network, it's just a different address.
2. Another possibility is to use a different type of source control.  Git or Mercurial comes to mind.  Both of these products are distributed version control systems.  Basically, if you aren't connected to a network, you still "submit" your product to the control system and, then, when you *can* connect back to the network, you merge your changes in with the main system on the network.  It works very well (though is a bit more complicated to understand than Subversion).

Hopefully that helps you.  (And, if it does, you can accept this as an answer to your question, which I would appreciate.)

Comment: sorry about that. but the problem is laptops are not connected to local network hence cant access the repository on local server. 
my question is that do i have to have repository over the net???

Comment: @Vikrant - No problem.  If you like my answer, could you please select the check mark next to my answer (up above).

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is designed to work effectively through Internet. Updates/commits uses delta algorithm to transmit only changed parts of tree.

Just do not forget to enable SSL encryption to prevent data sniffed.

Comment: do i need to have a webspace to do that ?? i mean do i need to upload the solution on the net ??